# CRLF in HTTP Chrome requests

Tags: http, newline

According to RFCs ([7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and [2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)) HTTP message is:

```
    generic-message = start-line
                      *(message-header CRLF)
                      CRLF
                      [ message-body ]
    start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line


   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
   field-name     = token
   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

So single `CRLF` is considered as EOL sign. But When I get request for Chrome or Firefox I see extra `CR`.

[image: Request HEX text]

What parsing rules should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Postel said in many RFCs, "be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send".

A well-formed client should never send something like this. But errors happen, and something must be applying newline conversions somewhere down the line. Thus, as long as you can safely handle these cases, parsing these newlines (and in general, any `\r*\n` sequence, to put it as a regex) as a single newline in the header should be the best way to do it.

If you can't parse the header at all, just return a Bad Request error.

Comment: What a comprehensive answer!

Comment: Actually, it's harmful. Google "race to the bottom". Just fail the request.

Comment: HTTP is so established and even pervasive as a standard that it's way past the point where any harm can be done this way.